# Unable to select checkbox using javascript in browser console

Tags: javascript, web-component, webapi

i am automating our application using a tool that supports javascript.Navigated to the page at browser console, i am trying to select the checkbox inside a web component using document.queryselector method but i am not able to succeed in checking the box.

tried `.checked = true`, select and submitform.

i am relatively new in this company and to the tool, so need some tip.

[image: screenshot attached]

Comment: `document.querySelector("selector expression").checked - true`

Comment: What is `.renderRoot`?

Comment: I presume the Web Component made the **default** ``.shadowRoot`` also available as ``.renderRoot``, strictly speaking not required.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman They might have proxied it though.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `querySelectorAll()` that return an array, so you need to specify the position of the array that you want to change. Actually in the image show that the function return an array with 2 elements.

Comment: that was a key find. thank you, got it working now. Soln was "renderRoot.querySelectorAll("selector")[0].checked = true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop or need to specify the position.

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('selector');
for (var i = 0, len = checkboxes.length; i < len; i++) {
//work with checkboxes[i].checked = true;
}
```